# React-router + subdirectory + parameters - How to use/configure?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to configure react-router in a subdirectory in a server to work with a router parameter?

Folder Structure:

```
SERVER (Root)
|
|- Some another site files
|
|- /contabilidade
     |
     | - react files (command npm run build)
|
|
```

Wanted URL: https://doces.jrpti.com/contabilidade/8 [where 8 is a parameter to API service]

When I call this URL, the navigator returns error 404.

My code:

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename="/contabilidade">
        <Route path="/:id" component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

On package.json, I configure:

```
"homepage": "https://doces.jrpti.com/contabilidade"
```

I'm using react-router 5.0.0

Some ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the issue is, but you need to make sure your server serves the `index.html` file for all your routes.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js, make sure that you are specifying the absolute path to your `bundle.js`. If you use the relative path, you're likely to get a 404.

Along with that, if you're using nginx,you could add the following to your nginx.conf:

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

This will make sure that all routes will be redirected to your index.html.

for development purposes, you can use the `historyAPIFallback` option in `webpack` if that's what you're using

Comment: I'm not using nginx.. I didn't find bundle.js... How Can I do what you said?

Comment: I think the react router is confusing the parameter [in the case, number 8] with a route....

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Another solution would be to add an environment variable where you're deploying.

for example, if you set a variable like:
```PUBLIC_URL=https://doces.jrpti.com/contabilidade'```
and then update all routes to use this like:

```<Route path="{process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/:id" component={App} />```

Also, may I ask what you're using to serve your app, if not nginx?

Comment: Your sugestion didn't work .. I don't know about nginx. In my app, I didn't install anything. I'm sorry, I'm new in react and I don't know some things.. Can You explain?